# ATI Graphics Driver has stopped working properly

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have repeatedly had my computer screen turn blank, and then when the screen returns everything is running slowly and this error message pops up.  I've checked for updates and it said that there were none but then I went a web site and downloaded Catalyst for my drivers. I have had one issue since then but that is better than was happening before. What else could I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> What else could I do to fix this problem?

Buy nVidia next time.

Comment: Plus one, i learned my lesson (For some reason i got another tablet with ATI, but it was at gunpoint)

Answer (score 0):

Make and model of the computer, model of the ATI board and version of the driver please.
Also laptop, desktop, thin client, SFF etc?

I had problems like that with a ATI 3200 mobility raderon on my TX2510us tabler PC from HP. one driver updated helped it, but it eventually killed the 2 year old machine. Its spare parts for now.

Comment: it's a laptop and the graphics card is an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470... also, it's a PC from Dell running windows 7

Comment: I've got a new HP tablet with a 5450. Have you completely removed all traces of an old driver before installing a new one. Have you tried getting the drivers from HP?